# Python dataframe if if if

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Why does my code not run when option2 is 1?

```
option2 = ""  
specificReport = "yes"


if specificReport == "yes":

    specificReport = str.lower(input("Do you want to look at the specific report (yes/no) : " ))

            option2 = str.lower(input("Which data are you looking for \
            (1. Location, 2. Type of Risk, 3. Risk Level , 4. Date & Time): "))
            if option2 == 1:
                locationValue = input('Enter the location you want to inspect: ')                   
                LocationRow = (dataframe.loc[dataframe['Location Name'] == locationValue])
                print(locationRow)
```

Comment: you code is neither minimal nor reproducible, so it's quite difficult to guess what you are doing, please update with reproducible code, input, and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the output of `input` is a string, so you compare `option2` (a string) with `1` (an integer). Either you convert the integer to string (i.e., `'1'` instead of `1`) or you convert the output of `input` to an integer (i.e., `int(option2)`).

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a string. You need to make it an int

`if int(option2) == 1`.

Also you don't really need str.lower() on the input - you can make in int() from there too.